# Permanent Hashtbl.hash collision on Parsetree.expression

Tags: hash, ocaml

Whatever I put into an `Exp.ident` argument, the result **always** yields the same hash value. Why is that?

```
utop # Hashtbl.hash (Exp.ident {Location.txt=(Longident.Lident "bar");loc=Location.none}) ;;
- : int = 99094472 

utop # Hashtbl.hash (Exp.ident {Location.txt=(Longident.Lident "foo");loc=Location.none}) ;;
- : int = 99094472

utop # Hashtbl.hash (Exp.ident {Location.txt=(Longident.Lident "");loc=Location.none}) ;;
- : int = 99094472
```

Does `Parsetree.expression` use some kind of magic datastructure that cannot be walked by the structural hash generator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to guarantee that `hash` always terminate, it has a maximum depth.
The same problem occurs when you have lists that start the same.

If this is necessary to you, a good solution is to create your own hash function, in the case of `Parsetree`, I suggest you take a look at [Ast_iterator](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/parsing/ast_iterator.mli).